# Compilation error: Invalid character in name at (1)

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran

I wrote

```
program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: N = 3
  real(8), parameter :: &
    A(N,N) = reshape( (/1.5d0,1d0,1d0,1d0,1.5d0,2d0,1d0,1d0,3d0/), shape(A) ) &
    b(N) = (/ 5d0,-3d0,8d0 /)

  print *, A
end program
```

saved as test.f, and got compilation error with `gfortran -ffree-form -Wall -Werror -ffree-line-length-none test.f`.

```
test.f:6:24:

     A(N,N) = reshape( (/1.5d0,1d0,1d0,1d0,1.5d0,2d0,1d0,1d0,3d0/), shape(A) ) &
                        1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
test.f:9:12:

   print *, A
            1
Error: Symbol ‘a’ at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

What's wrong?

The compiler is GNU Fortran (GCC) version 6.1.1.

Comment: Suggestions: Replace `real(8)` with a named constant, say, `use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: wp => REAL64`, then declare `real(wp) :: A(N,N).` Lastly, write literals as `1.5_wp, 2.0e+3_wp` and never any other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a comma before the declaration of `b`:

```
  real(8), parameter :: &
    A(N,N) = reshape( (/1.5d0,1d0,1d0,1d0,1.5d0,2d0,1d0,1d0,3d0/), shape(A) ), &
    b(N) = (/ 5d0,-3d0,8d0 /) !                                              ^ 
    !                                                                        |
    !                                                        comma inserted here
```